# How to get table name based on the HDFS location?

Tags: shell, hive

I would like to find out the table name based on the HDFS location using a shell script. 
Is it possible?

Comment: possible..if you named the folder with the table name.

Comment: What if the folder name is different?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a direct hive cli command to get that but you can check the Hive Metastore database/table (mostly MySQL/MariaDB db/table) to get Hive table name based on location, if you have access.